# main function in C with void and without void

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point

What is the difference between these two programs?
The 1st one i am getting 4,3,2,1 and 2nd one is compilation error.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    static int i = 5; 
    if (--i){ 
        printf("%d ", i); 
        main(10); 
    } 
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
    static int i = 5; 
    if (--i){ 
        printf("%d ", i); 
        main(10); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: In the second case, which `main()` which takes a parameter are you trying to call? The one you show is not it.

Comment: If you show the exact full error it will probably tell you more precisely what I mean.

Comment: It is a "formality", when you use `(void)` you are explicitly declaring that the function takes no arguments. If you later call `main(10);` of course it complains, you just told it `main` takes no arguments (plus that other little issue about `main` being the entry point for your program...)

Comment: Helpful read: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: The problem you're encountering is to do with any regular function, not only `main`.

Comment: Can any language-lawyers speak to the legality of declaring `int main()` vs. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or `int main(void)`?  Does that fall under implementation-defined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a function like this:

```
int func() { ... }
```

It says that the function takes an indeterminate number of arguments and returns an `int`.  So you can legally pass any number of arguments of any type  (although you won't be able to access them).

When you define a function like this:

```
int func(void) { ... }
```

It says that the function takes **no** arguments.  Attempting to pass any arguments to this function will result in a compile time error.

On a side note, recursively calling the `main` function is not a good idea.  You're better off either calling another function which is recursive or just using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The appearance of a solitary `void` in a parameter list explicitly tells the compiler "this function takes no arguments".

In the first code example, calling `main` recursively is permitted since there is no argument list, which permits any number of arguments (this may have been changed in a more recent C standard than the one supported by your compiler; I forget the specifics).

Variables declared `static` are stored in the process' data section rather than in stack memory, so they persist beyond their scope and retain their value across function calls, so `i` decrements on each call until it reaches zero and your program hits the base case (don't enter the `if` statement), and terminates.